# Forgot password Devise gem API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have been using Devise gem in my application. I could able to 
configure devise sessions_controller to respond to both request from web and
from mobile API call.

But now i am trying to see how i can use the Forgot Password option of Devise gem
for Mobile API call. I can able to use the sign in with API as like below

```
curl -X POST 'http://localhost:3002/users/sign_in.json' -d 'user[email]=balan@test.com&user[password]=123456'
```

can i do the same with forgot password?

Comment: Hi @balanv, I am searching for giving the authentication using devise for both web and api. Can i know how you have worked out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SagarBommidi: Please post this as separate question, i can provide you answer for this.

Comment: isn't this covered by the :recoverable module in the devise gem?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Got the answer.

1) Create a custom action which recieves `email` as input

2) Add below code

```
@user = User.find_by_email("email@email.com")
if @user.present?
 @user.send_reset_password_instructions
 render :text => "updated"
else
     render :text => "no such email"
end
```

Comment: You would be better off rendering the same message whether the user exists or not. As is, this action could be used to fish for valid user accounts.

Comment: Thanks @balanv! it is really helpful.

Comment: If someone needs also custom mail message: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-custom-mailer

Answer (score 7):

devise now supports it. Check the link bellow
 https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/API-Mode-Compatibility-Guide

**Password Reset Request (post)**

```
curl -X POST \
'http://{{protocol}}{{host}}:{{port}}/{{resource_plural}}/password' \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'Postman-Token: 406d7e49-7da5-460d-8cc2-1009da8fcb73' \
-H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
-d '{
  "user": {
      "email": "user@example.com"
  }
}'
```

**Password Reset Confirm (patch)**

```
  curl -X PATCH \
'http://{{protocol}}{{host}}:{{port}}/{{resource_plural}}/password' \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'Postman-Token: f68be2db-1b90-4443-be93-3f012ca4c7dc' \
-H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
-d '{
  "user": {
      "reset_password_token": "-96mB4zMSjL4t5N6ozGC",
      "password": "newpassword",
      "password_confirmation": "newpassword"
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 2):

I did this:

In `config/routes.rb`:

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do 
     resources :reset_passwords, only: [:index, :create]
  end
end
```

and in `app/controllers/api/v1/reset_passwords_controller.rb`:

```
class Api::V1::ResetPasswordsController < Api::V1::BaseController
   def index
    user = User.find_by_email(user_params)
    if user.present?
     user.send_reset_password_instructions
     render(
          json: "{ \"result\": \"Email already exists\"}",
          status: 201
        )
    else
      render(
          json: "{ \"error\": \"Not found\"}",
          status: 404
        )
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:email)
  end

end
```